# import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver*; import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Anyone one help the below error occur to run selenium web driver.

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver*;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

Answer (score 2):

Correct one is

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
```

Comment: webdriver statement does not work